# cannot install my driver

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, driver, windows-7-x64

I am new in the driver business.
I try to install my first driver, I download this driver: [File System Filter Driver Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43586/File-System-Filter-Driver-Tutorial)
When I try to install the driver ( after compile it in visual studio 2008) I get the following message in the even viewer: 
\??\c:\FsFilter.sys has been blocked from loading due to incompatibility with this system. Please contact your software vendor for a compatible version of the driver.

I try to switch the solution platform (now is win32) but my only options was: pocket pc, smartphone.... 
My operating system is windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 (or even Vista) and above require all drivers to be signed by Microsoft before they can be installed. There are ways of disabling that though like [here](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/how-to-install-use-unsigned-drivers-in-windows-vista-7-x64.127187/)